# JPA find in @PostContruct in @RequestScope does not reload

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, cdi

I have a Request Scoped Managed Bean where i do a JPA find to populate a property from the database. When ever i leave the page and make changes to the database records it does not reflect when i revisit the page where the changes should be shown i.e. The Managed Bean class with @PostContruct which load from the database.

ManagedBean here:

```
@PostConstruct
public void loadCurrentProfile() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
    Long id = (Long) externalContext.getSessionMap().get("id");
    serviceprovider = em.find(Serviceprovider.class, id);
}

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>companyProfileBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.suntech.winnoweb.jsfbeans.CompanyProfileBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>id</property-name>
        <value>#{param.id}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: Maybe you are using the wrong `@RequestScoped` annotation. Please update the question with your imports. Also, did you check if the method is called on page reload?

Comment: Do you commit the transaction?

Comment: Actually i added a record directly in the database

Comment: Your code is accessing an attribute of the session map.  `Long id = (Long) externalContext.getSessionMap().get("id");`  How exactly are you modifying the value?